# create coupon code for simple products with custom options

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to apply coupon code for products with custom options. i tried as below and its not working.....  i checked [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-shopping-cart-promotion-rule-for-product-with-custom-options/) , its 2013 post, still default magento dont support this ?  **is there any way** we can apply coupon code for custom option products ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have same price for all custom option products.... so creating shopping cart price rule with below condition worked for us.

[image]